# An Access vba solution for excel exe process not closing

Tags: vba, ms-access

I been dealing with an issue where after closing the Access vba code snippet that communicated with Excel the Excel task would remain in memory locking the Excel output file.

There are a surprising number of articles on that topic on the internet, but little in the way of a before then after example in Ms Access vba demonstrating a failure then a solution.  In the following example you can cause such by changing, and unchanging, the code lines that are commented out.

The following article towards its end has such an example that I have tested and it appears to work.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs-6647c4b4-da5c-ee1f-cc6f-58815d47702d

The Ms Access vba code follows; with just few changes to allow it to work in an Ms Access Form launched from a command button.

```
Private Sub cmdTest03_Click()

         Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
         Dim xlBook As Excel.WorkBook
         Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
         Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

         ' **********************************************************
         ' Use this VBA Code to hang Excel.exe after the code runs.
         '
         ' xlSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2)).Value = "Hello"

         ' **********************************************************
         ' Use his VBA Code to have a clean exit of Excel.exe after
         ' this code snippet runs.
         '
         xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(1, 1), xlSheet.Cells(10, 2)).Value = "Hello"
         
         xlBook.Saved = True
         Set xlSheet = Nothing
         Set xlBook = Nothing
         xlApp.Quit
         Set xlApp = Nothing

         Beep

    End Sub
```

The next challenge is incorporating this solution into some existing code.

I have spent weeks experimenting with different idea suggested of various publications including some from Stack Overflow, plus looking into some books, etc.

BTW, I am struggling with viewing an Excel spreadsheet using OLE which is going to be my next question.

Here is an failed example:

```
Public Sub cmdTest01_Click()

    Dim s01MainF        As String
    Dim sTableName      As String
    Dim sSheet          As String
    Dim sTemp01         As String

    s01MainF = "frmzzzX"
    sTableName = "zzz_p1r4c3_TEST"
    sTemp01 = ""
    sTemp01 = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\a01_Excel\"
    sTemp01 = sTemp01 & Format$(Now(), "yyyymmdd hh-mm-ss") & " "
    sTemp01 = sTemp01 & sTableName & ".xls"
    gsPathFile = sTemp01 & ""

    If FileExists(gsPathFile) Then
       DoEvents
       Call DeleteFile(gsPathFile)
       DoEvents
    End If

    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoCmd.OutputTo ObjectType:=acOutputTable, _
                ObjectName:=sTableName, _
                OutputFormat:=acFormatXLS, _
                Outputfile:=gsPathFile
    DoEvents
    DoEvents

    Me.txtTableName.Value = " " & sTableName

    DoEvents
    Dim rng              As Excel.Range
    Dim appExcel         As Excel.Application
    Dim WorkBook         As Excel.WorkBook
    Dim Wsheet           As Excel.Worksheet
    DoEvents
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set WorkBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(gsPathFile)
    Set Wsheet = WorkBook.Worksheets(sTableName)
    DoEvents
    appExcel.Visible = False

    DoEvents
    Call FreezeTopRowPane(Wsheet, appExcel, 1)

    DoEvents
    appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    WorkBook.SaveAs gsPathFile
    appExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
    DoEvents
    WorkBook.Saved = True
    WorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    DoEvents
    Set Wsheet = Nothing
    Set WorkBook = Nothing
    DoEvents
    appExcel.Quit
    DoEvents
    Set appExcel = Nothing
    DoEvents

    GoTo cmdTest01_Click_End  ' jump over the OLE stuff.

    DoEvents
    Set ctl = Me!OLEUnbound0
    With ctl
      ' Enable control.
      .Enabled = True
      ' Set Locked property to False.
      .Locked = False
      ' Allow embedded objects only.
      .OLETypeAllowed = acOLEEmbedded
      ' Specify the OLE server and the type of object.
      .Class = "Excel.Sheet"
      ' Specify the file to be embedded.
      .SourceDoc = gsPathFile
      ' Create the embedded object.
      .Action = acOLECreateEmbed
      ' Set Verb property to activate for editing.
      .Verb = acOLEVerbShow
      ' Activate object.
      .Action = acOLEActivate
    End With

cmdTest01_Click_End:

End Sub
```

I think the Excel problem is being caused by FreezeTopRowPane subrtn.

Like I said: The next challenge is incorporating this solution into some existing code.

I have scoured the Stack Overflow site along with many other sites around the world.

Update: Oops I forgot to include the code for the FreezeTopRowPane subroutine.

```
 Public Sub FreezeTopRowPane(ByRef MyWs As Excel.Worksheet, _
       ByRef TheApp As Object, _
       Optional ByVal AfterRowNr As Integer = 1)

Dim SavedWS As Worksheet
Dim SavedUpdating As Boolean

SavedUpdating = TheApp.ScreenUpdating  'save current screen updating mode

Set SavedWS = ActiveSheet            'save current active sheet

TheApp.ScreenUpdating = False        'turn off screen updating

MyWs.Activate                 'activate worksheet for panes freezing

ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False     'turn off freeze panes in case
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0             'set no column to split
    .SplitRow = AfterRowNr       'set the row to split, default = row 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True   'trigger the new pane freezing

SavedWS.Activate                  'restore previous (saved) ws as active

TheApp.ScreenUpdating = SavedUpdating 'restore (saved) updating mode

End Sub
```

Well I have something working.

I replaced the FreezeTopRowPane subroutine with the following code.

````
``` 

WorkBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Activate
WorkBook.Worksheets(1).Activate

With appExcel.ActiveWindow
     .FreezePanes = False
     .SplitColumn = 0             'set no column to split
     .SplitRow = 1                'set the row to split
     .FreezePanes = True
End With 

```
````

You will note there are number of "DoEvents" around the "DoCmd.OutputTo" which from my reading allows for said operation to finished.

Follows the improved code that is currently working.

````
```

' ****************************************************
' Improved Version of [cmdTest01_Click] test vba code
'
Public Sub cmdTest01_Click()

Dim s01MainF        As String
Dim sTableName      As String
Dim sSheet          As String
Dim sTemp01         As String

s01MainF = "frmzzzX"
sTableName = "zzz_p1r4c3_TEST"
sTemp01 = ""
sTemp01 = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\a01_Excel\"
sTemp01 = sTemp01 & sTableName & ".xls"
gsPathFile = sTemp01 & ""

If FileExists(gsPathFile) Then
   DoEvents
   Call DeleteFile(gsPathFile)
   DoEvents
End If

DoEvents
DoEvents
DoCmd.OutputTo ObjectType:=acOutputTable, _
            ObjectName:=sTableName, _
            OutputFormat:=acFormatXLS, _
            Outputfile:=gsPathFile
DoEvents
DoEvents

Me.txtTableName.Value = " " & sTableName

Dim appExcel         As Excel.Application
Dim WorkBook         As Excel.WorkBook
Dim Wsheet           As Excel.Worksheet

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WorkBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(gsPathFile)
Set Wsheet = WorkBook.Worksheets(sTableName)

appExcel.Visible = False

WorkBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Activate
WorkBook.Worksheets(1).Activate

With appExcel.ActiveWindow
     .FreezePanes = False
     .SplitColumn = 0             'set no column to split
     .SplitRow = 1                'set the row to split
     .FreezePanes = True
End With

appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
WorkBook.SaveAs gsPathFile
appExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

WorkBook.Saved = True
WorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set Wsheet = Nothing
Set WorkBook = Nothing

appExcel.Quit

Set appExcel = Nothing
DoEvents

GoTo cmdTest01_Click_End   ' Jump over the OLE Stuff.

DoEvents
Set ctl = Me!OLEUnbound0
With ctl
  ' Enable control.
  .Enabled = True
  ' Set Locked property to False.
  .Locked = False
  ' Allow embedded objects only.
  .OLETypeAllowed = acOLEEmbedded
  ' Specify the OLE server and the type of object.
  .Class = "Excel.Sheet"
  ' Specify the file to be embedded.
  .SourceDoc = gsPathFile
  ' Create the embedded object.
  .Action = acOLECreateEmbed
  ' Set Verb property to activate for editing.
  .Verb = acOLEVerbShow
  ' Activate object.
  .Action = acOLEActivate
End With

cmdTest01_Click_End:

End Sub

```
````

Now to tackle the OLE part of the test.

Comment: There is a theory that you also need to set `Workbooks` to its own object and then set it to nothing as well when you are done. But this is asked often and so far I have not seen a 100% working clear answer.

Comment: You haven't included the code for `FreezeTopRowPane`. -- Also, you should `Set Wsheet = Nothing` **before** closing the workbook it was created from. (I hope I'm not in cargo cult land there.)

Comment: The code is lifted from the linked Microsoft support post which refers to Excel 97.

Comment: The `FreezeTopRowPane` sub is very much the problem. All unqualified `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveWindow` uses will cause it.

Comment: @Andre - That for pointing out that problem of the unqualified ActiveSheet or ActiveWindow  with the  FreezeTopRowPane  subroutine.

Comment: @Andre - I have something working.  I confess that I had to use Google to lookup "qualified ActiveSheet or ActiveWindow".  I hope it is what you been talking about.  I learn a lot of going thru other peoples' code.   It seems to work.   BTW, way the only useful example I have found for using OLE on Excel is from a Microsoft document written in 1986.   (Pre Flintstones perhaps).